# How to display image in div from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, image

I had to display images one by one according to dates , each having an arrow image in between. Some thing like this :
A->B->C->D

I display that on a div.

The problem occurs when there are lot of images. The width of div is constant and the image go to the next line like this :

```
A->B->C->D->
E->F->G->
H->I
```

In this situation i wish to display the images like this (please see the arrow symbol image and image flow this time):

```
A->B->C->D->
G<-F<-E 
H->I
```

**Is there inbuilt control or any way to achieve this ?**

Comment: `float:right;` ? https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8axvzp83/

Comment: Could be a good idea. But how to get the width of div and how to apply logic that if the width of arrow image+the other image width sum go beyond the threshold width then reverse the display flow of image ?

Comment: And all that has to be done using html and javascript only.

Comment: Please also note that we do not know the size of image and arrow at static time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS + CSS

```js
var correctDirection = function() {
  var direction = null;
  var lastTop = null;

  $('div').each(function() {
    var $entity = $(this);
    var top = $entity.offset().top;
    if (lastTop != top) {
        lastTop = top;
        direction = direction == 'ltr' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
    }
    $entity.addClass(direction);
  });
};

correctDirection();
$(window).on('resize', correctDirection);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  top: 40%;
}

div.ltr {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div.ltr:after {
  content: '→';
  right: -20%;
}

div.rtl {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: right;
}

div.rtl:after {
  content: '←';
  left: -20%;
}

div:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you  please explain what is last and top ? also i would really appreciate if you could please explain me your logic and algorithm ? Thanks

Comment: `direction` variable contains css class name: 'rtl' or 'ltr'. `lastTop` contains position (offset from top) of div element. If position of last element (`lastTop`) and current (`top`) are different, it means that new line started and we need to change direction.

Comment: I really thank you for answer and help. But I am confused with top word. What i have in mind  is each time i add image, i get the width of it and compare it with the total width of div(which contains these images). If the sum is > then total width of div.
then i change the arrow direction and drirection flow.

Now how it is different from you logic of top ? could you please clear me

Comment: In my approach all images already in DOM. When document is loaded, I get first image, then get its position - the distance from the beginning of the document to the div element (`top`). Then I set css class 'ltr' to the first div. After - I get second image and its position. If second image is on other line, its top poisition will be different from first image. In that case I need to set css class 'rtl'. For other images logic is same: I change class name to opposite if line is changed (top position is changed). Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to add to your main raw div  `dir="rtl"`

For more information read here [CSS Direction](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/)

Comment: thaks for the answer, please also see the type of output i wish to have (i will need to deal with width of div, how to get it ? how to know the increasing div width dynamically on adding image and deciding that flow has to be ltr or rtl)

Comment: You can use `this document.getElementById("yourDiv").offsetWidth;` to get the width of tha image div, and also to get the main raw div, and then to calculate the if the main div are full, for the next div to add the attribute dir `$('div').attr('dir', 'rtl');`
This is the main idea, but it may be different belong to your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>
  .floatRight{ 
  }
  .clearBoth{
    clear:both;
  }
  .container{
    width:100%;
  }
  .container .floatRight{
    float:right;
  width:9%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background:#cdcdcd;

    height:100px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="floatRight">1</div>
<div class="floatRight">2</div>
<div class="floatRight">3</div>
<div class="floatRight">4</div>
<div class="floatRight">5</div>
<div class="floatRight">6</div>
<div class="floatRight">7</div>
<div class="floatRight">8</div>
<div class="floatRight">9</div>
<div class="floatRight">10</div>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```